# JNDI MariaDB con Tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jdbc

Buenas a ver si alguien ilumina mi camino, describo lo siguiente :

- tengo agregada la libreria (mariadb-java-client-2.1.2.jar) del driver en **D:\apache-tomcat-8.5.20\lib\mariadb-java-client-2.1.2.jar**
- añadida la dependencia al proyecto por maven :

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

  Entoces , cargo la configuracion de hibernate a traves de clase:

  ```
  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
      DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
  ```

```
//        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
```

```
//        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webdb");
```

```
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("java:comp/env/jdbc/mariaDB");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }
```

```
        private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

        //hibernate search
        properties.put("hibernate.search.default.directory_provider", "filesystem");
        properties.put("hibernate.search.default.indexBase", "/var/lucene/indexes");


        return properties;
    }
```

... y la configuracion de tomcat 8.5 
**server.xml**:

```
    <Resource name="jdbc/mariaDB"
          global="jdbc/mariaDB"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          driverClassName="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webdb"
          username="root"
          password=""

          maxActive="100"
          maxIdle="20"
          minIdle="5"
          maxWait="10000"/>
```

y en el **context.xml**:

```
    <ResourceLink name="jdbc/mariaDB"
          global="jdbc/mariaDB"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

como se puede observar hay un par de lineas comentadas en el datasource , si uso la configuracion de conexion directa no hay problema,  si uso la conexion al JDNI, me da siempre que no encuentra el driver , ¿quizas me falta agregarlo a alguna parte mas? , está en el tomcat , en la JDK , Y en la ependencia del proyecto, y siempre el mismo mensaje , dejo la traza:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to
>   open JDBC Connection for DDL execution    at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:69)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:67)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:329)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:120)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:65)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:313)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:401)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
>     ... 77 more
>
> `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for java:comp/env/jdbc/mariaDB     at`
>
> java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)  at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43)
>     ... 94 more

muchas gracias

Comment: Esta linea te quedo de sql? url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webdb" **yo la cambiaria por algo asi:** "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:numero_puerto/xxxxxx"

Comment: Nada , que no hay manera que ha decidido que no existe el Driver y no existe , he probado con varias versiones y hasta cambiando la BD y nada , hay algo que se me escapa, juraría que alguna vez en el curro he llegado a hacerlo con JNDI , pero no recuerdo que haya que añadir mas configuracion ni por parte del servidor ni de código , PD: tambien he probado con jdbc:mariadb://localhost:numero_puerto/xxxxxx infructuoso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien por lo visto solo hace falta poner la configuracion en el context.xml , y llamar al DS con el properties de hibernate o bien con el Context de naming , ya está solucionado , por si a alguien le pasa que revise la forma de llamar al DS y quite la config del server.xml , :D

Comment: Deberías cambiar el scope de la dependencia a provided, ya que la estás copiando también a nivel de servidor.